# Switch case messes up my array that im trying to convert

Tags: c, arrays, switch-statement

I'm new to C and im trying to convert letters to keys (as on old mobile keyboard) but the switch case somehow always ends up messing up the array. 
When I try to test the value it returns absolutely different character than there is in the array. e.g. character number 32 instead of capital V.

```
char *LetterToKey(char name[101])
{
    char number[101];
    bool unknwn = false;

    for(int i = 0; i<101; i++)
            {
                if(unkwn) break;
                switch (name[i])
                {

                case 'A':
                case 'B':
                case 'C':
                case 'a':
                case 'b':
                case 'c': number[i] = '2'; break;

                case 'D':
                //...

                default:
                    printf("%d\n", (int)name[i]);
                    unknwn = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return number;
}
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Already a note: you are returning a pointer to a variable which does **not** live anymore outside the function.

Comment: When asking a question about a run-time problem, as this question is doing, Please post a [mcve] so we can duplicate the problem and help you debug it

Comment: the array: `number[]` is local to the function, so 'disappears` when the function exits.   trying to  return the array will only return an address, on the stack, where the array: `number[]` was located.   Trying to access that array, after the function exits, results in undefined behavior

Answer (score 1):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. checks for errors
3. requires the caller to pass the returned pointer to `free()`
4. avoids the use of 'magic' numbers (like 101)
5. properly terminates the resulting character array so it does not contain trash/uninitialized characters

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <ctype.h>   // toupper()
#include <stdlib.h>  // calloc()
#include <stdio.h>   // printf()

#define MAX_BUF_LEN 101


char *LetterToKey( char *name )
{
    char *number = calloc( MAX_BUF_LEN+1, sizeof( char ) );
    if( !number )
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    // implied else, calloc successful

    size_t i = 0;

    while( i < MAX_BUF_LEN && number[ i ] ) 
    {
        switch ( toupper(name[i]))
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'B':
            case 'C':
                number[i] = '2'; 
                break;

            case 'D':
            case 'E':
            case 'F':
                number[i] = '3';
                break;

            // etc

            default:
                printf("unexpected char: %c\n", name[i]);
                number[ i ] = ' ';
                break;
        }
    }

    return number;
}
```

Of course, if the caller properly NUL terminated the input then the code can be simplified to:

```
#include <ctype.h>   // toupper()
#include <stdlib.h>  // calloc()
#include <stdio.h>   // printf()
#include <string.h>  // strlen()


char *LetterToKey( char *name )
{
    char *number = calloc( strlen( name )+1, sizeof( char ) );
    if( !number )
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    // implied else, calloc successful

    for( size_t i=0; number[ i ]; i++ ) 
    {
        switch ( toupper(name[i]))
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'B':
            case 'C':
                number[i] = '2'; 
                break;

            case 'D':
            case 'E':
            case 'F':
                number[i] = '3';
                break;

            // etc

            default:
                printf("unexpected char: %c\n", name[i]);
                number[ i ] = ' ';
                break;
        }
    }

    return number;
}
```

Comment: `// etc` - The whole switch could be optimized to just `number[i] = (toupper(name[i]) - 'A') / 3 + '2';`

Comment: @KamilCuk,  while that is true, I did not want to (greatly) disturb the logic given by the OP